# Create private static function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm using the following code to create: private property, private method, public property, public method and public static property.

```
function ClassA() {

    var privateProperty = 'private_default_value';

    var privateMethod = function() {
        console.log("private method executed ...");
    };

    this.publicProperty = 'public_default_value'; 

    this.publicMethod = function() {
        console.log("public method executed ...");
    };

    ClassA.publicStaticProperty = "public_static_default_value";

    // How to create here: ClassA.privateStaticProperty ?

};

var instance = new ClassA();
instance.publicMethod();
console.log(ClassA.publicStaticProperty);
```

How can I create a private static property in this class ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution using an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to create a scope visible by the the constructor `ClassA` :

```
var ClassA = (function(){

    var Constructor = function(){
        var privateProperty = "private_default_value";

        var privateMethod = function() {
            console.log("private method executed ...");
        };

        this.publicProperty = "public_default_value"; 

        this.publicMethod = function() {
            console.log("public method executed ...");
        };
    }
    Constructor.publicStaticProperty = 'public_static_default_value';
    var privateStaticProperty = "private_static_default_value";

    return Constructor;
})();
```

`privateStaticProperty` is "static" : there's only one property.

`privateStaticProperty` is "private" : you can't read it from outside the IIFE.

Comment: Rename `publicStaticProperty` to `privateStaticProperty`

Comment: @MBO So how to maintain the old public static property in this code also ? could you update it to contain both of public static and private static ... sorry, I get lost

Comment: Side note : in most cases it's better to define methods on the prototype (i.e. `Constructor.prototype.publicMethod = function()...`) as it avoids their useless duplication.

Comment: @dystroy I cannot access my public_property anymore ? same for private_property accessing inside the class. How in your code may I have non-static public and non-static private properties ?

Comment: @dystroy You have a bug, I'll edit your answer to fix it